# How load an animated GIF in pygame

Tags: python, pygame, animated-gif

I'm trying to open and run an animated gif on my pygame display. i have spent quite a few hours searching for an solution for this but i have not came across one yet.

thank you in advanced for you help!

Comment: This question is actually duplicate: [How can I load an animated GIF and get all of the individual frames in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29571399/how-can-i-load-an-animated-gif-and-get-all-of-the-individual-frames-in-pygame)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) clearly states that GIF's wont be animated.  However, you could dissect the GIF into frames, or sprites or still images in that matter, and animate them yourself. You can find free tools that can generate those frames.

Comment: There are projects to facilitate it: http://pygame.org/project-GIFImage-1039-.html

Answer (score 1):

Pygame doesn't support animated GIFs natively, and you'd need [**GIFImage**](http://pygame.org/project-GIFImage-1039-.html) for that. But probably the author deleted it.

You could use a spritesheet or separate images for your sprite frames. [**Here**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/SpriteIntro.html) a tutorial for Sprites.

You could fix that problem simply, to get animation you have to do break up your images after then load them using by [**pygame.image.load()**](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html) and in your main game logic, run that pictures. It will be an animation as a GIF image, except it's a little bit long process because you have to seperate frames. Also don't forget to use Sprites.

For seperate images: [**GIMP**](http://www.gimp.org/downloads/) Amazingly simple to use it.